# Combining Two Separate Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach

I have two separate arrays in my PHP mail form that are different sets of checkboxes: *webdetails* and *graphicdetails*. Only one set will be filled out (the other will be hidden unless a previous radio button is selected.) I'm wondering how to reference them correctly in my PHP.

This is what I used to get one to post, but not two:

```
foreach($_POST['webdetails'] as $value1) {
    $webdetails_msg .= "$value1\n";
}
```

How do I add graphicdetails in there? Duplicating the snippet gives me ***Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()***

I don't know much more PHP than this, so an explanation would be appreciated.

--

Here's the PHP I get an error with:

```
<?php
/* Set mail headers */
$myemail  = "my.email@gmail.com";
$subject    = "New Request";

$webdetails         = $_POST['webdetails'];
$graphicdetails     = $_POST['graphicdetails'];

foreach($_POST['webdetails'] as $value1) {
    $webdetails_msg .= "$value1\n";
}
foreach($_POST['graphicdetails'] as $value2) {
    $graphicdetails_msg .= "$value2\n";
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "
Details:
$webdetails_msg
$graphicdetails_msg
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

<?php exit(); } ?>
```

HTML for webdetails:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="webdetails[ ]" id="design" value="Design" />
<input type="checkbox" name="webdetails[ ]" id="development" value="Development" />
<input type="checkbox" name="webdetails[ ]" id="web-updates" value="Web Updates" />
<input type="checkbox" name="webdetails[ ]" id="forum-template" value="Forum Template (Full)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="webdetails[ ]" id="forum-graphics" value="Forum Graphics" />
<input type="checkbox" name="webdetails[ ]" id="web-other" value="Other" />
```

HTML for graphicdetails:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="graphicdetails[ ]" id="graphic-logo" value="Logo Design" />
<input type="checkbox" name="graphicdetails[ ]" id="graphic-social" value="Social Media Graphics" />
<input type="checkbox" name="graphicdetails[ ]" id="graphic-other" value="Other" />
```

Comment: Are all the `<input>`'s in the same `<form>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks fine so I am guessing it's this:

Checkboxes don't get posted if they are not checked, you need to check there are any

```
if (isset($_POST['graphicdetails'])){
    foreach($_POST['graphicdetails'] as $value1) {
        $webdetails_msg .= "$value1\n";
    }
}
```

But in any case

```
if (isset($_POST['graphicdetails'])){
    $webdetails_msg .= implode("\n", $_POST['graphicdetails'])."\n";
} // you don't need the curly braces for 1 line but SO has a small code width
```

is less to write